# Print all list items of particular user in SP list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, printing, button

It's my first time here and very new in SP.  I have created a list for overtime of staffs.  one overtime per list item.  At the end of the month, the requirement is to print all overtime made by a staff (for that month) in one page. Maybe a Print button.

Can someone help me on how to accomplished this? Results should be Filtered by Name and Month.

Fields needed are:

Name   |  Date of OT | Description | OT Hours  |

At the last row it should have the "Total OT Hrs" which will sum of all Over Time Hours.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From previous experience, the majority of the time for any reporting and filtering I would export the list to Excel. Then add in custom calcs in Excel to generate the totals.

Alternatively, you could:

- Create a page
- Include the List webpart on the page
- Customise the list view with the filters you have described.
- Add custom code with either Content editor or script editor webparts to calculate your totals, place a 'Print' button on the page.

You did say you were new to SharePoint so the second option may require some learning. I would have included some links but some guides may differ based on the version of SP you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.  Exporting to excel is what I was doing...however, its the "boss" who wanted it to be in SP, where he can just filter the staff name and Month (when the overtime was taken) to print the report.  I already created a "Datasheet View" that has filter and totals...but i can't seems to find out how I can print it with a custom form.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Have you tried using Javascript within a script editor webpart?

Find or create a short script to print the page, and include it in script editor webpart.

Which version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Nope have not tried JS within a script editor...however I tried putting a Print button on a content editor using the html editor "<code><input onclick="window.print();return" type="button" value="Print"/></code>"

Comment: the above code only gives a snapshot of the form...we are using sharepoint 2010

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delay in reply - did you make any progress ?

Comment: Thank you for your follow-up...No...there are no progress on this but still looking on ways how to proceed.  For the meantime we have the window print (as stated in the code on my previous comment) and I am exporting to excel.